# HTML5 type="range" this.value returns undefined

Tags: html, angular, typescript, rangeslider

I'm trying to make a range input, but when I try to pass it to my function, it returns undefined:

HTML:

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
    <label>Setpoint</label>
    <p>{{channel.setPoint}}</p>
    <div>
         <p>5</p>
         <p>30</p>
    </div>
    <input type="range" min="5" max="30" value="50"  step="0.5" class="slider"
        [(ngModel)]="channel.setPoint" (onchange)= "putSetpoint(channel, this.value)">
    <br>
</div>
```

TS file:

```
putSetpoint(cb: Channel, value: number) {
    console.log(value);
    cb.setpoint = value;
    this.homedata.setpointChannel(cb);
}
```

Comment: `min="5" max="30" value="50"` - is not valid

Comment: oups!.. but still the same result with: <input type="range" min="5" max="30" value="channel.setPoint"  step="0.5" class="slider"  (change)= "putSetpoint(channel, this.value)">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.value` does not refer to anything , you have to tell Angular that you are referring to the value of the `input` :

```
 <input #inputRange type="range" min="5" max="30" value="50"  step="0.5" class="slider"
        [(ngModel)]="channel.setPoint" (onchange)= "putSetpoint(channel, inputRange.value)">
```

Comment: It work... but last question: why does angular cast it as a string in my json put request instead of number... even if my Channel.setpoint  interface in a number ?